# How to find Woocommerce Products without a Featured Image

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to create a SQL Query that will output the Woocommerce products in my MySQL Database that do not have a featured image assigned to it.  As Woo is based on Wordpress, I'm not sure where to get the information from but it looks as if I will need to join some tables up.

Has anyone out there had experience with this?  I have 500 products and all need to have a Featured Image.  I am going through them randomly and assigning each product one, but I need to see how many are left to do and which ones need to be done.

I am unable to sort the Products by Featured Image in the Woocommerce backend so I am hoping it can be achieved via SQL Query.

It looks as if I have found the right query. It joins some tables to give me a list of all products and featured images. I can then sort this list and see what products have NULL Featured Images. The SQL Query I used is below in case it helps somebody:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.post_title, pm.*
FROM wp_posts p
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    AND pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
WHERE p.post_type IN ( 'product' )
```

Answer (score 4):

This would be my query. It will return all post id's ( same as product id's ) that have no image

```
select ID FROM wp_posts WHERE ID NOT IN (select post_id from wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key="_thumbnail_id") AND post_type="product"
```

Comment: Suggest, to add `AND post_status!='auto-draft'` in the end of query to  remove auto-drafts from result.

Answer (score 3):

Create a View called `Products_List`:

```
SELECT
    `wptt_posts`.`post_title` AS `post_title`,
    `wptt_posts`.`post_name` AS `post_name`,
    `wptt_postmeta`.`meta_value` AS `meta_value`,
    `wptt_posts`.`ID` AS `ID`
FROM
    (
        `wptt_posts`
        JOIN `wptt_postmeta` ON (
            (
                `wptt_posts`.`ID` = `wptt_postmeta`.`post_id`
            )
        )
    )
WHERE
    (
        (
            `wptt_posts`.`post_type` = 'product'
        )
        AND (
            `wptt_postmeta`.`meta_key` = '_sku'
        )
    )
ORDER BY
    `wptt_postmeta`.`meta_value`
```

Then create another query using `Products_List` above:

```
SELECT
Products_List.ID as "Product ID",
Products_List.meta_value as "SKU",
Products_List.post_name as "Product Name",
Products_List.post_title as "Product Title",
'NO' AS "HAS FEATURED Image"
FROM
    Products_List
WHERE
    ID NOT IN (
        SELECT
            Products_List.ID
        FROM
            Products_List
        LEFT JOIN wptt_postmeta ON Products_List.ID = wptt_postmeta.post_id
        WHERE
            wptt_postmeta.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
    )
UNION
SELECT
Products_List.ID as "Product ID",
Products_List.meta_value as "SKU",
Products_List.post_name as "Product Name",
Products_List.post_title as "Product Title",
'YES' AS "HAS FEATURED Image"
        FROM
            Products_List
        LEFT JOIN wptt_postmeta ON Products_List.ID = wptt_postmeta.post_id
        WHERE
            wptt_postmeta.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
```

Comment: How can we use the second Products_List query?

Comment: After you create the view in the first query, you can then access the "Products_List" view in future queries

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility that does not use a NOT IN :

```sql
SELECT p.ID, p.post_title 

FROM `wp_posts` as p LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON (p.ID=pm.post_id AND pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id') 

WHERE p.post_type = 'product' 
AND 
(meta_key IS NULL OR meta_value = "")
```

Answer (score 0):

is possible whith sku ? ( no only id)

```
SELECT p.ID, p.post_title 
FROM `wp_posts` as p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_postmeta pm 
    ON (p.ID=pm.post_id AND pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id')
WHERE 
    p.post_type = 'product' 
    AND (meta_key IS NULL OR meta_value = "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple as that. The following sql returns sku of all products with the default woocommerce image (means all products without image):

```
select wp_postmeta.meta_value from wp_postmeta where wp_postmeta.post_id IN (select ID FROM wp_posts WHERE ID NOT IN (select post_id from wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key="_thumbnail_id") AND post_type="product" AND post_status!='auto-draft') AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = "_sku";
```